# How to insert line of php code in html file, using SimpleHtmlDOM

Tags: php, html-parsing

I'm trying to insert `THE PHP CODE` between the `<div id="container">` THE PHP CODE HERE `</div>` . I'm using the http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ in this Php Html Parser.

I've got this so far, how to find a div having an id called container:

// Find all  which attribute id=foo

```
$ret = $html->find('div[id=foo]');
```

Then after finding the foo, what's next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html->find('div[id=foo]')->innertext = 'bar';
```

Should do the job but you might be better off modifying the DOM with JS?

Comment: Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Comment: You are setting up an instance of the class right? e.g. `$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');`

Answer (score 0):

Why not modify the source Wordpress template instead of trying to hack in the text later? That PHP snippet could potentially produce a huge chunk of text, and you can't insert it verbatim into the DOM - you can only insert its output (which you'd have to capture with `ob_start()/ob_get_clean()` anywyas).

Comment: i'm not trying to hack a wordpress template, i'm currently developing a project that is connected with wordpress template.